# How can I uninstall MusicJukeBox?

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall

I have recently installed Music JukeBox. Post-installation, it is not working properly. I want to uninstall MusicJukebox, however, I get an error message:

> The Path is not valid/Program maybe corrupted. Uninstall will not
>   continue.

How can I uninstall this program?

Comment: Update - I used RevoUninstaller (see below for more details),it did not remove the files/folders which I had to remove manually. I will keep you posted if I have any further problems/conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice guide on how to do that: [TechGuy Board](http://forums.techguy.org/all-other-software/461256-solved-problem-uninstalling-musicmatch-jukebox.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
When I looked for any process such as mmjb, mim etc., I do not fnd any in my Task Manager. 
I also get the following error message when I try to uninstall using Add/Remove programs (Step 2 in the link provided). 
The log file 'f:\program files\musicmatch\musicmatch jukebox\uninst.isu' is not valid or the data has been corrupted. Uninstallation will not continue. 

What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using [RevoUninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)

This searches and deletes all registry files and leftover files and folders from a program

Comment: I was able to uninstall(?) using RevoUninstaller, but I do not think  that it was a clean uninstall. It has removed it from Add/Remove Programs, however it was available in Start>Programs menu, which I manually deleted. Also, I had installed it on F:\Program Files\MusicMatch\MusicMatch Jukebox and when I navigate to that screen, I find all files and folders intact(?). There are lots of dll's, Configuration Settings etc., 

Systech - Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you pick "Advanced" uninstall mode?

Comment: Yes, I did choose "Advanced" uninstall mode.